# jQuery Mobile Select input text on focus

Tags: jquery, select, mobile, focus, highlight

I'm using jQuery mobile, I now want to make an input text field to be highlighted when tapped.

I'm using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.highlight').focus(texty_focus);
});
function texty_focus() {
    var input = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() { 
        input.select();
    },10);
}
```

But it's not working on my mobile. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.highlight').click(function(){
         var input = this;
         input.focus();
         input.setSelectionRange(0,999); 
     });
});
```

Comment: Do you have an live example of this issue?

Comment: Try it now with my recent change

Comment: However, is there a way we can make the field read-only? I tried to use `readonly="readonly"` but the highlight wasn't working (on mobiles).

Comment: Not sure how that would work... I would suggest writing a JavaScript function that prevents changes but still keeps the input boxes default function (perhaps warrants another question)